# Escaping double questionmark in if statement

Tags: bash

I am trying to make a function that counts changed, added, new, etc files in the local git repo. I am using `git status -s` for this and it returns `?? somefile` if a file is untracked. The `??` part is the part I check to determine what type of entry it is. 
However when checking with

```
if [ "${lPrefix}" == '??' ]; then ...
```

All changes `uu, m, a, d` are counted as untracked.

How can I make sure that the check works as intended and only triggers on untracked files.

I have tried replacing `??` with:

- `"??"` -> did not work, guessing it is because `?` is a wildcard
- `"\?\?"` -> did not work, expected it to work
- `'\?\?'` -> did not expect it to work as `'` means literal

**EDIT:** As requested by Jack Bracken
The lPrefix is set as follows(it is also all code where the problem lies)

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    arr=($line)
    lPrefix="${arr[0]}"
    if [ "${lPrefix}" == '??' ]; then lPrefix="N"; fi
    ...
done < <(git status -s)
```

Comment: Have you tried '??' yet? Bash evaluates things in double quotes, but treats things in single quotes literally.

Comment: it is the one that is currently used, and somehow does not work

Comment: Is it acceptable to you if you route all the "?? xxx" lines to a separate file and then work on that file?

Comment: It might be, that is if you can filter just those lines @alok

Comment: Can we see how you  get the value of lPrefix?  Have you tried echoing its value inside your if statement and confirming it is what you think it is?

Comment: You aren't quoting `$line` when you set array; there is a good chance you have one or more files in the current directly with a two-character name, and `??` is expanding to those file names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems here:

1. you're dangerously using an *antipattern* to split a string (and here it's actually a dangerous move since your string *does* contain the glob characters `?`),
2. you're parsing the high level command (aka *porcelain* command in `git`'s terminology) `status`.

First, fix the second problem: use `git status --porcelain` or, rather `git status -z` (which implies `--porcelain`), to have entries separated by a null byte (which makes parsing safe). We'll then parse using `read` with the null delimiter: `-d ''`

To fix the first problem, I'll try to understand what you want to do: each line given by `git status -s` (or, rather `git status --porcelain`) starts with a code; if this code is `??` then set `lPrefix` to `N`, otherwise set `lPrefix` to the code found.

This should then do:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' line; do
    lPrefix=${line:0:2}
    filename=${line:3}
    if [[ $lPrefix = '??' ]]; then lPrefix=N; fi
    # other stuff...
done < <(git status -z)
```

---

Why did your command fail?

It's difficult to tell exactly, but it's probably related to the antipattern you used to split the string:

```
arr=($line)
lPrefix="${arr[0]}"
```

This is very bad! it's a (sadly) very common antipattern, given by people who don't really understand (or overlook) how the shell performs word splitting and filename expansion: if the expansion `$line` contains glob characters (i.e., `*`, `?`, `[...]` and extended globs if `extglob` is on), then the shell will not only perform word splitting, but also perform filename expansion, that is, it will match every glob with found files.

In your case, if you happen to have filenames with 2 characters (e.g., a file named `ab`) in the current directory, then `${arr[0]}` will be this file! Look:

```
$ mkdir test
$ git init
$ touch a ab abc xy
$ ls
a  ab  abc xy
$ git status -s
?? a
?? ab
?? abc
?? xy
$ while IFS='' read -r line; do arr=($line); declare -p arr; done < <(git status -s)
declare -a arr='([0]="ab" [1]="xy" [2]="a")'
declare -a arr='([0]="ab" [1]="xy" [2]="ab")'
declare -a arr='([0]="ab" [1]="xy" [2]="abc")'
declare -a arr='([0]="ab" [1]="xy" [2]="xy")'
$ # see the filename expansion?
```

---

Note also that I didn't use

```
while read state file; do ... ; done < <(git status -s)
```

or something similar (like in the accepted answer) to get the state and the file name, because that would trim leading and trailing newlines in both `state` and `file`.

Comment: Why do the best answers come after accepting a different answer???
Anyway, I have found the problem(appeared that I declared a different array with a different name...) , and I have changed my code according to your answer. 
As a bit of a newbie to bashscripting, these long answers are by far the best, as there is usually a lot of explaination in them, so thanks a lot for this answer

Comment: Imo globbing is not of an issue here since the string is quoted

Answer (score 2):

The `??` should not be a problem here. I guess your variable `${lPrefix}` isn't properly set. I tried the following code and it worked:

```
git status -s | while read state file ; do
    [ "${state}" = '??' ] && echo "${state} new"
done
```

---

However using bash for this is not really efficient. I strongly recommend to use `awk` like this:

```
git status -s | awk '{c[$1]++}END{for(i in c){print i, c[i]}}'
```

Explanation in multiline version:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# c(ount) is an associative array, indexed by the values of the first column
# like '??', 'u', 'm' and so on. Each time they appear we
# increment their count by 1
{ c[$1]++ }

# Once the end of input has been reached we iterate trough
# c and print each index along with it's count.
END {
    for(i in c) {
        print i, c[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: explaination please

Comment: Ok, I'll add that

Comment: I was more interested in what happens after awk. I guess it iterates though every line and every new prefix is added and every recurring prefix is raised by one?

Comment: @chepner Thanks! Good catch!

Answer (score 2):

Whenever scripting with the output of `git`, it's best to use `-z` to work with null-separators.

I would recommend changing your script to this:

```
git status -z | while read -r -d '' status file; do 
    [ "$status" = '??' ] && printf '%s\n' "$file"
done
```

As mentioned in the comments (thanks), if left unquoted, the `??` will expand to the name of any files with exactly two characters in their name. Adding quotes ensures that the question marks are treated as literal characters. Adding quotes results in consistent behaviour, whether using `[` or the bash-specific `[[`.

When you want simple string matching, my advice would be to use `[` with `=` (and don't forget to quote your variables, as always!).

I'm assuming that you plan on executing some shell command for every file with `??` status. Otherwise, remember that the shell isn't designed for text processing, so you should be using a tool such as awk/sed.

Comment: ++; however, note that _quoting_ the RHS inside `[[ ... ]]` also performs literal string comparison - no need to resort to `[ ... ]`: `[[ '??' == '??' ]] && echo match || echo nomatch; [[ 'ab' == '??' ]] && echo match || echo no match; [[ 'ab' == ?? ]] && echo match || echo no match`

Comment: @mklement0 thanks, that's good to know. I've incorporated some of what you said into my answer but I didn't want to get too much into the intricacies of `[` vs `[[`!

Answer (score -1):

You can try :

```
cat 1.txt | grep -Po "(?<=\?\?\ ).*"
```

1.txt is:

```
?? aaa
!! bb
?? vv
~~ xx
```

Break-down:

`grep -Po` Perl expression, show only matching lines
`("?<="` Starts with
`\?\?\` Escaped question marks and a space
`).*` Anything coming after that initial match